# Chocolatey commands not running remotely

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

when i am running chocolatey through powershell  locally it`s working fine but when i try to run the chocolatey commands from remote machine it says choco is not recognized.All other commands are working fine remotely.

Please Help

Comment: Also is there a way to set default source for chocolatey package during 
 chocolatey installation like i don`t want https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/

Comment: Obvious question first... Have you installed chocolatey on the remote machine?

Comment: yes chocolatey is installed n running fine on remote machine

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that remotely the chocolatey path was not accessible, Once I changed to Chocolatey path the commands started working

Comment: don't forget to use .\ if you are running chocolatey commands remotely